# How can I find the last coordinate in a MGLPolyline?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, mapbox

I have some code which is supposed to find the first and final coordinate in an MGLPolyline. Currently, I am able to find the first and the middle value, but am not able to find the last value. Bellow is my code. In it, you can see how I find the first and middle coordinate.

```
var arrayOfCoordinates = [CLLocationCoordinate2D]()
var arrayOfPolylines = [MGLPolyline]()


 for value in arrayOfPolylines {
        mapView.addAnnotation(value)

        //This is for the first and last snakehead and tail stuff
        let lastLoc = value.coordinate.latitude
        let newLoc = value.coordinate.longitude

        let firstCor = value.coordinates[0].latitude
        let secondCor = value.coordinates[0].longitude
       ...
```

I have tried the following to find the value:

```
value.coordinates[value.coordinates.count] //This does not compile as it says
```

> Value of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer' has no member 'count'

***So my question is how can I find the last value (coordinate)?***

Comment: Please show more code. Specifically, how is `arrayOfPolylines` declared?

Comment: See edit... @Magnas

Comment: User123 has answered your question but it is important to understand that arrays are zero based. This means that the first element is index zero, the second is index one, etc. So the last element is index `array.count - 1` when you use `array.count` you are trying to access an element beyond the end of your array.

Comment: Yes, I know But it does not matter as it was invalid to do .count @Magnas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, your code will not work for this. With the current code, you would not be able to find the last value easily, you would have to do a mathematical process to determine the count of coordinates then check if the for loop has run through enough time to reach the last coordinate.

But an easier way is to create instead an array of `CLLocation` which then you can access with the following code:

```
            let lastLoc = self.arrayOfLocationList.last //last value here
            let newLoc = self.arrayOfLocationList.first
```